# Solution Multiplicity of the Diophantine Equation $k = b(a - \gcd(a,b))$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $f(k) = | \{ (a,b) \in \mathbb{N}^{2} \, | \, k = b(a- \gcd(a,b)) \}|$. It is clear that $f(0)$ is infinite since one may take any $b \in \mathbb{N}$ and any divisor of $b$ as $a$. From numerical experiments, however, it appears that $f(k) = 1$ if and only if $k \in \{1,2,6, 42,1806 \}$, so $f(k) = 1$ is finite. What of $f(k) = n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>1}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$? Is it infinite or finite as a function of $n$?

I conjecture that the number of $k$ satisfying $f(k) = n$ is finite for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(k)$ is finite.

For example, computer experiments show that $f(57600) \geqslant 226$, while $\tau(57600) = 81$, as the following pairs (not a complete list) solve the equation $57600 = b(a-\gcd(a,b))$:
\begin{array}{cc}
 22 & 2880 \\
 25 & 2880 \\
 26 & 2400 \\
 27 & 2400 \\
 28 & 2400 \\
 31 & 1920 \\
 33 & 1920 \\
 34 & 1800 \\
 35 & 1920 \\
 36 & 2400 \\
 37 & 1600 \\
 38 & 1600 \\
 41 & 1440 \\
 44 & 1440 \\
 45 & 1920 \\
 49 & 1200 \\
 50 & 1440 \\
 51 & 1200 \\
 52 & 1200 \\
 54 & 1200 \\
 56 & 1200 \\
 61 & 960 \\
 62 & 960 \\
 63 & 960 \\
 64 & 1200 \\
 65 & 960 \\
 66 & 960 \\
 68 & 900 \\
 70 & 960 \\
 72 & 1200 \\
 73 & 800 \\
 74 & 800 \\
 75 & 960 \\
 76 & 800 \\
 82 & 720 \\
 85 & 720 \\
 88 & 720 \\
 90 & 960 \\
 91 & 640 \\
 95 & 640 \\
 96 & 1200 \\
 97 & 600 \\
 98 & 600 \\
 99 & 600 \\
 100 & 720 \\
 101 & 576 \\
 102 & 600 \\
 104 & 600 \\
 108 & 600 \\
 121 & 480 \\
 122 & 480 \\
 123 & 480 \\
 124 & 480 \\
 125 & 480 \\
 126 & 480 \\
 130 & 480 \\
 132 & 480 \\
 135 & 480 \\
 140 & 480 \\
 146 & 400 \\
 148 & 400 \\
 150 & 480 \\
 151 & 384 \\
 152 & 400 \\
 153 & 384 \\
 160 & 720 \\
 161 & 360 \\
 164 & 360 \\
 170 & 360 \\
 180 & 480 \\
 181 & 320 \\
 182 & 320 \\
 185 & 320 \\
 190 & 320 \\
 193 & 300 \\
 194 & 300 \\
 196 & 300 \\
 198 & 300 \\
 200 & 360 \\
 202 & 288 \\
 204 & 300 \\
 241 & 240 \\
 242 & 240 \\
 243 & 240 \\
 244 & 240 \\
 245 & 240 \\
 246 & 240 \\
 248 & 240 \\
 250 & 240 \\
 252 & 240 \\
 255 & 240 \\
 256 & 240 \\
 257 & 225 \\
 260 & 240 \\
 264 & 240 \\
 270 & 240 \\
 280 & 240 \\
 288 & 240 \\
 289 & 200 \\
 292 & 200 \\
 296 & 200 \\
 300 & 240 \\
 301 & 192 \\
 302 & 192 \\
 303 & 192 \\
 306 & 192 \\
 320 & 240 \\
 322 & 180 \\
 325 & 180 \\
 340 & 180 \\
 360 & 240 \\
 361 & 160 \\
 362 & 160 \\
 364 & 160 \\
 365 & 160 \\
 370 & 160 \\
 380 & 160 \\
 386 & 150 \\
 387 & 150 \\
 401 & 144 \\
 404 & 144 \\
 416 & 144 \\
 451 & 128 \\
 480 & 240 \\
 481 & 120 \\
 482 & 120 \\
 483 & 120 \\
 484 & 120 \\
 485 & 120 \\
 486 & 120 \\
 488 & 120 \\
 490 & 120 \\
 492 & 120 \\
 495 & 120 \\
 500 & 120 \\
 504 & 120 \\
 510 & 120 \\
 520 & 120 \\
 540 & 120 \\
 577 & 100 \\
 578 & 100 \\
 600 & 120 \\
 601 & 96 \\
 602 & 96 \\
 603 & 96 \\
 604 & 96 \\
 606 & 96 \\
 612 & 96 \\
 641 & 90 \\
 650 & 90 \\
 721 & 80 \\
 722 & 80 \\
 724 & 80 \\
 725 & 80 \\
 728 & 80 \\
 730 & 80 \\
 736 & 80 \\
 740 & 80 \\
 760 & 80 \\
 769 & 75 \\
 771 & 75 \\
 800 & 80 \\
 802 & 72 \\
 808 & 72 \\
 901 & 64 \\
 902 & 64 \\
 961 & 60 \\
 962 & 60 \\
 963 & 60 \\
 964 & 60 \\
 965 & 60 \\
 966 & 60 \\
 970 & 60 \\
 972 & 60 \\
 975 & 60 \\
 980 & 60 \\
 990 & 60 \\
 1020 & 60 \\
 1153 & 50 \\
 1154 & 50 \\
 1201 & 48 \\
 1202 & 48 \\
 1203 & 48 \\
 1204 & 48 \\
 1206 & 48 \\
 1208 & 48 \\
 1212 & 48 \\
 1216 & 48 \\
 1224 & 48 \\
 1248 & 48 \\
 1285 & 45 \\
 1441 & 40 \\
 1442 & 40 \\
 1444 & 40 \\
 1445 & 40 \\
 1448 & 40 \\
 1450 & 40 \\
 1460 & 40 \\
 1480 & 40 \\
 1601 & 36 \\
 1604 & 36 \\
 1801 & 32 \\
 1802 & 32 \\
 1804 & 32 \\
 1921 & 30 \\
 1922 & 30 \\
 1923 & 30 \\
 1925 & 30 \\
 1926 & 30 \\
 1930 & 30 \\
 1935 & 30 \\
 1950 & 30 \\
 2401 & 24 \\
 2402 & 24 \\
 2403 & 24 \\
 2404 & 24 \\
 2406 & 24 \\
 2408 & 24 \\
 2412 & 24 \\
 2424 & 24 \\
 2881 & 20 \\
 2882 & 20 \\
 2884 & 20 \\
 2885 & 20 \\
 2890 & 20 \\
 2900 & 20
\end{array}

Comment: I believe your list is incomplete; it's missing pairs such as $(b,a)=9600,9)$. The actual value of $f(57600)$ seems to be equal to $274$. Also, the list of $f(k)=1$ numbers seems to be missing $6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any fixed $b$, there are only finitely many possible values of $\gcd(a,b)$; the divisors of $b$. Thus, we can let $g$ go over all divisors of $b$, calculate corresponding value of $a$ and check if $g$ is indeed equal to $\gcd(a,b)$. Expressed as a double sum, we have

$$ f(k)=\sum_{b\ |\ k} \sum_{g\ |\ b} \left[\gcd\left(\frac{k}{b}+g,b\right)\stackrel{?}{=}g\right]$$
where the summed quantity is equal to $1$ if the equality is satisfied and $0$ otherwise. This proves that $f(k)$ is finite for $k\geq 1$ and provides a loose upper bound on its value.

On the other hand, let $p$ be any odd prime. Then, there are just three possible pairs of $(b,g)$: $(1,1)$, $(p,1)$ and $(p,p)$; of which precisely first two satisfy the requirements. Thus, $f(p)=2$ for all odd primes $p$, making $\{k\ |\ f(k)=2\}$ infinite. Of course, primes are not the only numbers with this property.